# Sum of numbers in a given Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, performance, optimization, fibonacci

My task is to determine whether the sum of numbers in the Fibonacci series from A to B is divisible by the number D.

I use the fast doubling algorithm to find the required number in the series, and use the formula: 
 F<sub>a</sub> + ... + F<sub>b</sub> = F<sub>b+2</sub> - 1 - (F<sub>a+1</sub> - 1) - to determine the sum of the series, but this is not enough. For testing, I took a series from A = 10,000,000 to B = 20,000,000, the number D = 987654, the program was executed in 3.3 seconds, this is a lot. Are there ways to optimize my code?

```
class Solution {

    private static Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> previousValuesHolder;
    static {
        previousValuesHolder = new HashMap<>();
        previousValuesHolder.put(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO);
        previousValuesHolder.put(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE);
    }

    private static BigInteger totalSum;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nb = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int d = in.nextInt();

            totalSum = calculateTotalSum(a, b);
            System.out.println(checkSum(totalSum, a, b, d));
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger calculateTotalSum(int start, int finish) {
        BigInteger res1 = fibDoubleFast(finish + 2).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        BigInteger res2 = fibDoubleFast(start + 1).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

        return res1.subtract(res2);
    }

    private static String checkSum(BigInteger sum, int start, int finish, int d) {
        BigInteger result = sum.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(d));

        return result.longValue() > 0
                ? String.format("F_%s + ... + F_%s is NOT divisible by %s", start, finish, d)
                : String.format("F_%s + ... + F_%s is divisible by %s", start, finish, d);
    }

    private static BigInteger fibDoubleFast(int n) {
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
        int m = 0;
        for (int bit = Integer.highestOneBit(n); bit != 0; bit >>>= 1) {
            BigInteger d = multiply(a, b.shiftLeft(1).subtract(a));
            BigInteger e = multiply(a, a).add(multiply(b, b));
            a = d;
            b = e;
            m *= 2;

            if ((n & bit) != 0) {
                BigInteger c = a.add(b);
                a = b;
                b = c;
                m++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    private static BigInteger multiply(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) {
        return x.multiply(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be the correct place for this question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to terminate the calculations as soon as you have a number that is divisible by D?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it makes no sense, even if I enter only 1 row, the test still does not pass in time

Comment: You misunderstood me, I meant you should rewrite calculateTotalSum so it returns as soon you have found a number. Anyway it was more of a suggestion to investigate rather than a solution.

Comment: Got you. I already thought about this, but did not figure out how to find the sum of a series with the search for only one number in the series

Comment: 1. There is no point in doing `.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1))` for `res1` and `res2` when you’re returning `res1.subtract(res2)` anyway. `(x - 1) - (y - 1)` is the same an `x - y`. 2. There is no reason to declare `totalSum` as a `static` variable. 3. Don’t use `String.format` for something that can be expressed as plain string concatenation. 4. Remove unused stuff, `previousValuesHolder` severves no purpose, `m` is never used. 5. A simple way to avoid redundant computations, is to add a cache to `multiply`.

Answer (score 0):

For small values of D (less than 2^31, I think) , you could do the whole code using long, and do mod D for every intermediate result.

```
private static long fibDoubleFastModD(int n, long m) {
        ...
        long d = (...) % m;
        long e = (...) % m;
        ...  
}
```